# Codeigniter 2 model does not recognize db object

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've used Codeigniter 1.7 before and now I've upgraded to Codeigniter 2. I'm trying to write a very simple model:

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Model{

 function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }

 function test(){
  $this->db->orderby ( 'updateDate', 'desc' );
  $this->db->where ( 'logicalDelete', 0 );
  $rs = $this->db->get ( 'act_activity_vw' );

  if (! $rs) {
   throw new DatabaseException ();
  }

  return $rs->result ();
 } 
}
```

And i have a simple controller that calls it. but when i try to run it i get the following error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function orderby() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\API\application\models\test.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

It seems like it does not recognize 'db' as an object member.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried order_by instead of orderby ?

Comment: you flow is wrong there should be first where condition then order by aslo use order_by this is correct

Comment: yes, it is another change from previous version.

Comment: @raheel : it does not matter with active records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the database in your CodeIgniter system. You can do that with autoload or load it in the constructor of the class.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

I think that has everything you need.

Comment: Thanks, completley forgot about that.